# How to divide time between particular minutes in php

Tags: php

I have Two fields like time-from and time-to and time-took for particular people so my job is

```
ex: time-from: 10:00:00
time-to : 1:20:10
time-took : 30 (min)
```

So i want to display the order like that:

```
10:00:00 , 10:30:00 11:00:00, 11:30:00, 12:00:00, 12:30:00, 1:00:00, 1:20:10
```

Comment: The problem you have with your code, or desired output, is how any code is meant to distinguish between 1:20:10 AM and 1:20:10 PM. You need to use, or it would be easier to use 24 hour notation, so 01:20:10 and 13:20:10.The other part will be is the times restricted to a single day, or can they go over into two days?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the times into a time stamp using the PHP function "mktime", you then have the number of seconds difference between the dates. If the date is irreverent, then you could just use the same day for all of the times.

```
// The time to get the number of seconds from.
$tmpStr = "01:10:20";

// Break the string into components.
$timeArray = split(":", $tmpStr);

// The date element is redundant but needs to be set.
$timeInSeconds = mktime ($timeArray[0], $timeArray[1], $timeArray[2], 1, 1, 1970);
```

Now having the time in seconds from midnight allows you to order them accordingly and to also compare two times to find out the difference.